# Date comparision in Geneos

Tags: geneos

I have a requirement where I need to compare start time with current time and if the value is greater than certain limit I need an alerting.
Can someone share the syntax.

Ex:

I have a column called start time with below syntax.

Start Time >> 2015-12-03 15:04:02.0

I want to put a rule like

if (now()-value) > 3600 then severity critical

THis syntax doesn't work, can someone pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make your value from string to Date first.

Use this :

```
set $(dateValue) parseDate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', value)
if (now()- $(dateValue)) > 3600 then 
  severity critical
endif
```

You may want to read the detail for parseDate function from the "Gateway2 Reference Guide.pdf" document.

Comment: thanks for answering.
I have a slight problem.
My Geneos server is US based and the datevalue is UK.
how can I handle such scenario?

Comment: I have experience in adding / subtracting the offset in seconds to the time as a constant. The time value in Geneos is always represented in seconds so it can be add / minus directly with numbers.

Comment: Of coz, you will need to consider the daylight saving effect between US / UK.

Comment: RE your other question, firstly, I doubt Geneos support nested loop. You can try. As I remember, the rule block doesn't really allowing all kind of programming structure. Secondly, Time on gateway (now()) should be local system of the gateway host, rather than GMT. Not 100% sure again, you might want to raise to ITRS.

Answer (score 0):

set $(rowname) target "rowName"

set $(state) path "job_state" value

set $(a) now()

set $(b) parseDate("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:S.%f", value)

set $(c) $(a) - $(b)

if $(state) <> "ENDED OK" then

if $(c) > 3600 then

severity warning

endif

endif

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally....

You can define the Timezone of the gateway as GMT in the Operating Environment which will affect what is returned with the function `now()` . This way you can deal with daylight savings in a controlled fashion.

[image: TimeZone]

ParseDate() can also take a timezone which will again help automatically calculate correctly for daylight savings.